# I'm trying to position an image so it has the same position on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, image

I'd like to begin with that, I looked through various solutions here, but none of them worked for me.
My problem is that I'm trying to position this little image but it changes it's position with different screen sizes.
I tried putting it in a div with a relative position and give the image an absolute on but it still doesn't work.
Part of the code:

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="logome">
  <img src="nanana.png" alt="logo" /></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logome {
  top: 20%;
  right: 28%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: When using percentages in a position it is going to move based on the size of the container. Try using pixels instead.

Comment: But isn't that the whole point of using percentages? So it has the same position based on the screen size? Isn't using pixel the opposite? Sorry I'm still a newbie to all of this.

Comment: Check this out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/w4Lqr5cj/). `.c` has the exact same position attributes for each of the parent divs but the position is different.

Comment: But if you look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/w4Lqr5cj/1/) `.d` has position values that aren't percentage based but are in the same position as each other regardless of their parent.

Comment: So , in this example the "parent" is the screen ? Because I got a bit confused there.I think I understand what your point is. So, I should just use px instead of percentages with absolute position and it will work on all screen sizes ?

Comment: In the fiddle the parent would be the divs with the `a` or `a b` class. I can remake it using your code for a better example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/press/w4Lqr5cj/2/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should to use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:483px) and (min-width:310px)
{
  .What you need to resize{
 }
 .Wht you need to resize{
 }
}
```

Comment: Play with differents sizes max and min

Comment: I don't need to resize it . I just need it to have the same position on every screen .

Comment: @RumenLasev Your example does have the same position on every screen, at least the top left corner does.

Comment: Width are variable @MrListener, Yes but if you need to have the same position with diferrents screens, You must to resize the image...

Comment: @MrLister I've been testing it on a website that shows how it looks like on different screen sizes and it doesn't look the same to me .
Should I post a link of the whole website ?

Comment: @RumenLasev You can, but it's better if you explain what you want more precisely. For instance, must the image resize, must the image have the same distance to the left or the right screen edge, etc. I don't know what you want, and until I do, I can only guess.

Comment: Well , basically what I want is to put an image between 2 lines of text.On my screen it looks perfect, on others , it goes up or down or right.

Comment: @RumenLasev Even without any CSS at all?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few comments but I feel like I should expand on them a bit.

The problem is the percentage based position values. Percentage will scale with the size of the parent. If you set it to be 25% to the left, no matter how big or small the parent its, it will **always** try and be 25% to the left.

However, with pixel position, when set to 25px the element will always try and be 25px to the left.

Example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/w4Lqr5cj/1/) - Sorry it looks bad but it makes the point!

**Edit** Relevant [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/w4Lqr5cj/2/)

```css
.a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.a.b {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.d {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div class="a b">
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>

<div class="a">
    <div class="d"></div>
</div>
<div class="a b">
    <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```